# Call C++ COM IDispatch interface from a background thread in C#

Tags: com, com-interop

So I have a c++ ATL COM component, which calls my C# component that exposes a COM visible interface.The ATL COM component passes an Interface pointer to my C# component so my c# code can call back into the ATL object. the ATL component is used in a windows forms app.

OK so, in order to do its work, the c# component needs to spin a thread and watch for things to happen.

Here is my question. 
Can I safely access, in managed code background thread an object that is a an interface pointer to an  STA object?

in c++ classic COM, you need to marshal and unmarshal the interface.
do i need to do that in managed code? if so how?

Comment: The CLR automatically marshals when it converts *object* to `IDispatch*`.  Or more typically *dynamic* in your source code, it is *object* at runtime.  You don't have to help.

Comment: OK It is a little concerning to depend on the :magic:

Comment: Then use a debugger to verify and make you feel good.